# Flip Transition from a Tableview Custom Cell to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a custom tableview cell that gets displayed in my tableview. Upon user tapping the cell, I would like to create a flip horizontal transition to a new view controller. How to do this either using Core Animation or UIView?

Sorry I am a newbie can't find the right way to do it anywhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS" to learn about view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You are talking about this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Create the next view controller.
     DetailViewController *detail= [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [detail setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:detail animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

For Dismiss:

```
-(IBAction)close:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

write this method in `DetailViewController` and  call this method to back.

Comment: This part works, but what would I do to flip transition back to the original view controller I navigated from?